# ArrayDeque and LinkedBlockingDeque

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, deque

Just wondering why they made a `LinkedBlockingDeque` while the same non concurrent counterpart is an `ArrayDeque` which is backed on a resizable array.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` use a set of nodes like a `LinkedList` (even though not implementing `List`).

I am aware of the possibility to use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` but what if one wanted to use an `ArrayBlockingDeque`?
 Why is there not such an option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really a problem you're stating (consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask especially "there is no actual problem to be solved")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This May not be a proper question w.r.t stackoverflow.
But i would Like to say something about these implementations.

-> First thing We need to answer why we give Different implementations for a certain Interface.
    Suppose we have a interface A and There are two implementations of that Let say B and C.
    Now suppose these implementations offer same functionality through their implementation.
    But B has a better performance than C.
    Then we should remove the Implementation except for two reason

```
1. Backward Compatibility - marking as deprecated.
2. There is a specific scenario where we cannot use B implementation.
```

For example:

**HashMap and LinkedHashMap** -> 
If i need ordered Keys i will use LinkedHashMap  otherwise I will Use HashMap (for a little   performance gain).

**ArrayBlockingQueue vs LinkedBlockingQueue**
    if i need Bounded Queue i will use ArrayBlockingQueue otherwise i will use LinkedBlockingQueue.

Now Your question **Why there is no ArrayBlockingDeque while LinkedBlockingDeque exist**.

First Let see why ArrayDeque exist.

From Java docs of ArrayDeque.

- This class is likely to be faster than
- {@link Stack} when used as a stack, and faster than {@link LinkedList}
- when used as a queue.

  Also note ArrayDeque doesn’t  have  Capacity Restriction. 
  Also it has Two pointers for head and tail as use use in LinkedList implementation.

**Therefore if there would have been ArrayBlockingDeque**.

```
1. There would have been no Capacity Restriction, which we normally 
   get from ArrayBlockingQueue.

2. There would have guards to access to tail and head pointers
   same as in LinkedBlockingDeque and therefore no significant performance 
   gain over LinkedBlockingDeque.
```

So to conclude there is no ArrayBlockingDeque implementation because there in nothing 
extra this implementation could provide over LinkedBlockingDeque. If you can prove there is 
something then yes, implementation need to be there :)

Comment: so at this point why making ArrayBlockingQueue based on an array at all? I mean would not be the same having a  bounded LinkedBlockingQueue? Since there is no random access.. where would be the problem? Thanks for replying

Comment: This analysis is wrong in several aspects. For example it does not consider caching, it does not consider the class overhead introduced by the list elements of the linked lists, ...